# Return string from MemoryStream which contains xml content

Tags: wpf-controls

Why my return content is always null;

```
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
                XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(root);
                xdoc.Save(sw);

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), true))
                {
                    string content =  sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return content;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 sw.Flush();
 ms.Position = 0;
```

to reset the starting point of your stream in order to read it agian.